# Where not null using Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, filter

I have a mySQL database with a `Website` field that is of type VarChar. Some of these fields will be null on the database.

I have an MVC application that I sending the database information to.

I am trying to set up a filter on the Index page so I can filter by certain columns. I am using the `Request.QueryString` to do this.

```
 switch (Request.QueryString["FilterOptionSelect"])
            { case "CountyName":
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filteredText))
                    {
                        filteredText = filteredText.ToUpper();
                        var modelFiltered = from n in model
                                               where n.CountyName.ToUpper().Contains(filteredText)
                                               select n;
                        return View(modelFiltered);
                    }
                    break;
               case "Website":
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filteredText))
                    {
                        filteredText = filteredText.ToUpper();
                        var modelFiltered = from n in model
                                            where n.CountyWebsite.ToUpper().Contains(filteredText)
                                            select n;
                        return View(modelFiltered);
                    }
                    break;

}
```

The only problem I have is on the Website case. It gives me a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on the WHERE CLAUSE of the Website case. When I debug, my model is not null (it has 130+ items inside...some with website info and some without website info).

I have already tried using the Lambda method (which had the same problem). I have also tried using `where n.CountyWebsite.ToUpper().Contains(filteredText) && n.CountyWebsite != null` which did not work either.

Comment: I would suggest you not use the Request object directly.  MVC hides those details.  If you create s model with a property or method parameter called FilterOptionsSelect MVC will push the value in for you.  There are very few reasons to ever directly use Request or Response when building with MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with your second attempt, but you need to switch the order of those statements.

```
where n.CountyWebsite != null && n.CountyWebsite.Contains(filteredText)
```

Just like all the other && operators, you don't want to evaulate any websites that are null, so do that operation first.

Also, .Contains in EF automatically is case-insensitive, so you don't need the ToUpper().

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think this will solve.

```
!String.IsNullOrEmpty(n.CountyWebsite) && n.CountyWebsite.Contains(filteredText)
```